# How to arc text in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how to curved text in flutter with RTL supported
I tried many things but it didn't work

```
class ArcText extends StatelessWidget {
  const ArcText({
    Key? key,
    required this.radius,
    required this.text,
    required this.textStyle,
    this.startAngle = 0,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double radius;
  final String text;
  final double startAngle;
  final TextStyle textStyle;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => CustomPaint(
        painter: _Painter(
          radius,
          text,
          textStyle,
          initialAngle: startAngle,
        ),
      );
}

class _Painter extends CustomPainter {
  _Painter(this.radius, this.text, this.textStyle, {this.initialAngle = 0});

  final num radius;
  final String text;
  final double initialAngle;
  final TextStyle textStyle;

  final _textPainter = TextPainter(textDirection: TextDirection.rtl);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.translate(size.width / 2, size.height / 2 - radius);

    if (initialAngle != 0) {
      final d = 2 * radius * math.sin(initialAngle / 2);
      final rotationAngle = _calculateRotationAngle(0, initialAngle);
      canvas.rotate(rotationAngle);
      canvas.translate(d, 0);
    }

    double angle = initialAngle;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      angle = _drawLetter(canvas, text[i], angle);
    }
  }

  double _drawLetter(Canvas canvas, String letter, double prevAngle) {
    _textPainter.text = TextSpan(text: letter, style: textStyle);
    _textPainter.layout(
      minWidth: 0,
      maxWidth: double.maxFinite,
    );

    final double d = _textPainter.width;
    final double alpha = 2 * math.asin(d / (2 * radius));

    final newAngle = _calculateRotationAngle(prevAngle, alpha);
    canvas.rotate(newAngle);

    _textPainter.paint(canvas, Offset(0, -_textPainter.height));
    canvas.translate(d, 0);

    return alpha;
  }

  double _calculateRotationAngle(double prevAngle, double alpha) =>
      (alpha + prevAngle) / 2;

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

I created this just inside container
I copied this code from the following link 'https://developers.mews.com/flutter-how-to-draw-text-along-arc/'

```
ArcText(
                  radius: 100,
                  text: 'أنت كا رمحمأيت في أحسن ',
                  textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                  startAngle: -pi / 2,
                ),
```

I just did this and it didn't work
Can someone help me with this problem

Comment: may be you can try this, https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_arc_text

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't support rtl